shading artifacts after subdivision


got these strange "indentations" on a flat surface with a "subdivide surface" modifier


can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

yes, I put a link to it in my post

you have non-planar faces caused by these 2 vertices. All vertices within this area have a Y of -1 but these 2 vertices have -0.99976. Set them both to -1 and the shading problem will go away. Also at the top of your object you need to fix the geometry.

